# Is there any disadvantage to using a dynamic return type on my API endpoints?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am currently building a web api service using MVC and I am creating the endpoints.  For example, my GET endpoint will execute a stored procedure and return the data in JSON format.  The model of the data returned can vary in the future and it seems like using a dynamic return type would remove the need of having to change the model and mapping every time that happens.  Basically, here is some sample code, do you notice any malpractices in my implementation?

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    [Route("companies/{id}")]
    public dynamic GetCompany([FromUri] int id, string userId)
    {
        var parameters = new Hashtable
        {
            {"UserID", userId},
            {"CompanyID", id}
        };
        var result = MyDB.ExecuteSp(CompanyReadByIdSp, parameters);

        return result;
    }
```

In fact, this would enable me to transform the object and add whatever I want to it without needing to worry about the model.  Is this a bad way of doing things?  Thanks ahead.

Comment: Convention is that you should always return HttpResponseMessage (or IHttpResponse) and the contents of the data should be in the response body, like this:  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new SuccessResponseWrapper<OBCReviewDetail>()
            {
                Data = content
            });

Comment: I haven't seen that in any of the services built at work.  We're building .NET MVC web api services.  Does that still apply?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realize that MVC wraps the return in a HttpResponseMessage.  So it would wrap the dynamic object in it when it returns.